# How to solve the error which occurs when using from pickle.load() function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle

I would like to load a dataset in IPython Environment and and use it.

In the directory containing the dataset, I've got these files:

- batches.meta
- data_batch_1
- data_batch_2
- data_batch_3
- data_batch_4
- data_batch_5
- readme
- test_batch

I wrote this code:

```
import os
import pickle as pickle
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Function Definition
def load_CIFAR(ROOT):
xs=[];
ys=[];
for b in range(6):
    f = os.path.join(ROOT, "data_batch_%d"%(b+1));
    X, Y = load_CIFAR_batch(f);
    xs.append(X);
    ys.append(Y);
Xtr = np.concatenate(xs);
Ytr = np.concatenate(ys);

del X, Y;
Xte, Yte = load_CIFAR_batch(os.path.join(ROOT, "test_batch"));
return Xtr, Ytr, Xte, Yte

#Function Definition
def load_CIFAR_batch(filename):
with open(filename, 'r') as f:

    ****** Here is where  error occurs
    datadict = pickle.load(f);
    ******
    X = datadict['data'];
    Y = datadict['labels'];
    X = X.reshape(10000, 3, 32, 32).transpose(0,2,3,1).astype("float");
    Y = np.array(Y);
    return X, Y;
```

But, when I used this function for loading this dataset with following command, I came across with [a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'] error.

```
#The directory of my dataset in my hard drive
url = 'D:\\OTIWU\\data\\cifar10'
Xtr, Ytr, Xte, Yte = load_CIFAR(url)
```

above is a command that I've used.

```
The whole error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-f0576df4fbda> in <module>()
----> 1 Xtr, Ytr, Xte, Yte = load_CIFAR(url)

<ipython-input-10-fedf6bd7c144> in load_CIFAR(ROOT)
      4     for b in range(1,6):
      5         f=os.path.join(ROOT, "data_batch_%d" % (b, ));
      ----> 6         X, Y=load_CIFAR_batch(f);
      7         xs.append(X);
      8         ys.append(Y);

      <ipython-input-13-368cd3e9d8d2> in load_CIFAR_batch(filename)
      1 def load_CIFAR_batch(filename):
      2     with open(filename, 'r') as f:
      ----> 3         datadict = pickle.load(f);
      4 
      5         X = datadict['data'];

      TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

How can I solve such problem?

Comment: Where are you `pickling` the data? It seems you need to use `pickle.loads(...)` instead of `pickle.load(...)`

Comment: Show us how the pickle file is created.

Comment: @JohnGordon Sorry man, I have to edit the context of questions?

Comment: Edit your post to include the code where the pickle file is created.

Comment: Also, python isn't C or Java.  Don't end your lines with semicolons.

Comment: @JohnGordon I'm actually a java developer.

Comment: @JohnGordon I've marked that in load_CIFAR_batch() function.

Comment: That's where you're READING the picked file.  Show us the code that CREATES the file.

Comment: @JohnGordon , Man I think file is created before, i want to load it. I think the procedure is: Open the file with this command: with open(filename, 'r') as f: and then reading with pickle . Am I right?

Comment: @tglaria, I changed my code as you suggested me but it's thrown another errorType: a bytes-like object is required, not '_io.TextIOWrapper'

Comment: have you tried with open(<filename>, 'rb') to read in binary mode? just an idea, this could be the reason

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. It's a problem related to python 3.x. when I ran it with python 2.x, I could read all the data from dataset. I also have to say that I've changed a little bit the source code. I mean I used from cPickle library Instead of Pickle and all of the source code except this issue is same as before.

Answer (score 0):

You need to open your file in *binary mode*:

```
with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
```